# iOS swift app l lost the option to switch the keyboard language when I change the app language to english

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a problem in my app keyboard, I have two language arabic and english, when I choose arabic language all good I can type in arabic or change it to english normal case as in any app,but when I changed the language of the app to english I only can type in english and the switch option is now for emojis not switch to arabic, so l lost the option to switch the keyboard language when I change the app language to english, but when the app is in arabic I can switch the keyboard language like any normal app.

```
static func switchLanguage() {
    // Get the user's device language
    let currentLang = Locale.current.language.languageCode!.identifier
    print ("currentLang: \(currentLang )")
    let newLanguage = currentLang == "en" ? "ar" : "en"
    
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue([newLanguage], forKey:"AppleLanguages")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("languageChangedTitle", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("languageChangedMessage", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
        //exit(0)
    }))
    
    if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
       let viewController = windowScene.windows.first?.rootViewController {
        viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[here are the images so you can see (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v42na.jpg)

[here are the images so you can see (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02sWc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you long press on that emoji button, you will see options to choose the keyboard to use. It has an option to guide you to the keyboard settings.

In Keyboard Settings, choose "Arabic". Then change it to "Arabic (PC)"